# Query to search for similar strings in Android Room

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

Imagine that i have a table like this in my room android database:

```
TABLE : PostalCode

id | cod   | ext   | city
-----------------------------------
1  | 2640  | 275   | Mafra
4  | 2695  | 650   | São João da Talha
...
```

When the user searches in editText something like this:

```
"São João"
"sAo joA da TaLH"
"sao talha"
"talh joa"
"joao talha"
```

I want to give him in the RecyclerView the second tuple
 "4  | 2695  | 650 | São João da Talha"

I don't know how to make this query...

```
select * from PostalCode where ... ?
```

Comment: http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-like/ maybe this could be useful

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the data from room, apply a loop to the list you get, store city for each loop if it contains the given string by user like:

```
if(STR.contains("searched terms")) { 
   list.add(str);
}
```

Then show the list.